Can someone help me understand "primitive accumulation"?
I'm reading Mark Neocleous's War on Waster (Chapter 2) and the problem of "primitive accumulation" is mentioned and I can't figure out what it means in more simple terms.

Primitive accumulation of capital.

It means "sociopathic money grubbing" — snatching whatever you see, in total disregard for other people.
Marx' canonical example involves moving into a new land, declaring that you discovered it, driving native people off of it by killing them and burning down their houses, partitioning it, fencing the partitions, and then renting it back out to the poor, homeless bums whose peaceful lives you destroyed.
I had to read Marx for a writing class, to imitate his style. I always thought he was naive, with his idea that jobs are interchangeable, that you ought to be able to take a day off to go fishing whenever you want, and the factory will just replace you that day with a spare module from the worker pool.
But this is great! I guess factory workers were indeed commodities back then.
Then he says,

This primitive accumulation plays, in political economy, the same part as original sin does in theology.

WOH!

In times long gone-by there were two sorts of people; one, the diligent, intelligent, and, above all, frugal elite; the other, lazy rascals, spending their substance, and more, in lazy rascals, spending their substance and more on riotous living.  Thus it came to pass that the former sort accumulated wealth, and the latter sort had at last nothing to sell except their own skins.

Yeah, that's me, alright!

Riotous living? Check!
Lazy rascal? Check! Toss in, "goofy and emotionally retarded."
Spending my substance? Well, I spend money on a substance, so check!
Sell my own skin?

Knowledge is not power. Truth is not beauty, either.
But he says that this John Galt / Hank Reardon cock 'n bullshit is a deliberate myth. Like religion, it's one of many used to herd the suckers who actually do  work every day into creating the wealth that these indolent, porcine factory owners absorb.

And from this original sin dates the poverty of the great majority that, despite all its labour, has up to now nothing to sell but itself,

I hear ya! Viva la raza! Sell that thang!

and the wealth of the few increases constantly, although they have long ago ceased to work.

Eat the Rich!
"Lickety-split, your place or mine?" says Melania.
